# Firebase DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to my type Object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app in Android Studio and tried everything to read my database into the type Object I have set up and I'm stuck on this error, would really appreciate some help:
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to my type object.

This is my snapshot and eventlistener setup that is producing the error:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_country_details);

    databaseCases = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    lvCases = findViewById(R.id.lvSearchResults);
    countryList = new ArrayList<CountryDetails>();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseCases.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            countryList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot caseSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                CountryDetails cases = caseSnapshot.getValue(CountryDetails.class);
                countryList.add(cases);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
}
```

This is my CountryDetails class minus some setters and gettters:

```
String Country;
String NewConfirmed;
String NewDeaths;
String TotalConfirmed;
String TotalCases;
String TotalRecovered;

public CountryDetails() {


public CountryDetails(String C, String NewC, String NewD, String To, String To, String Tot {
    this.NewC = NewC;
    this.New= NewD;
    this.TotalC = TotalC;
    this.C = C;
    this.To = To;
    this.Tot = Tot;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    Country = country;
}
```

And this is what my database structure looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/adhoi.jpg

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having wrong reference if you are trying to fetch data of Countriesnode

### Solution Code (add "Countries" in reference)

```
databaseCases = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Countries");
```